# elasticsearchで最新の情報をAPIで取得する方法について。

Tags: elasticsearch

elasticsearchを使っているのですが、APIで値を取得する方法が分からず困っているため、ご教示頂ければ幸いです。

下図のようなデータが1分毎に入ってきているのですが、最新の情報を取得する方法を教えて頂けないでしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

例
17時32分時点（最新時点）での[status.200] の合計値。

```
curl -XGET 'http://10.1.37.29:9200/ssp_nginx/_search?pretty' -d '
> {
>   "fields": [ "status.200"]
> }'
```

このクエリで最新の[status.200]が取得されるものかと思ったのですが、見てお分かりになられますように違っております。

```
{
  "took" : 33,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2484888,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "ssp_nginx",
      "_type" : "report",
      "_id" : "AVMkyBW3z7QeAQK4eWjC",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "status.200" : [ 3062 ]
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "ssp_nginx",
      "_type" : "report",
      "_id" : "AVMkyBXOq_jM0m5v7D3L",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "status.200" : [ 496 ]
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "ssp_nginx",
      "_type" : "report",
      "_id" : "AVMkyBXOq_jM0m5v7D3S",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "status.200" : [ 34 ]
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "ssp_nginx",
      "_type" : "report",
      "_id" : "AVMkyBXOq_jM0m5v7D3V",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "status.200" : [ 17251 ]
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "ssp_nginx",
      "_type" : "report",
      "_id" : "AVMkyBXOq_jM0m5v7D3W",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "status.200" : [ 2 ]
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "ssp_nginx",
      "_type" : "report",
      "_id" : "AVMkyBXOq_jM0m5v7D3Z",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "status.200" : [ 1139 ]
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "ssp_nginx",
      "_type" : "report",
      "_id" : "AVMkyBZtq_jM0m5v7D3i",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "status.200" : [ 15 ]
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "ssp_nginx",
      "_type" : "report",
      "_id" : "AVMkyBZtq_jM0m5v7D3l",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "status.200" : [ 1085 ]
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "ssp_nginx",
      "_type" : "report",
      "_id" : "AVMkyBZtq_jM0m5v7D3o",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "status.200" : [ 86 ]
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "ssp_nginx",
      "_type" : "report",
      "_id" : "AVMkyBZtq_jM0m5v7D3p",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "status.200" : [ 36 ]
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[_timestamp](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html)が有効になっていれば、ソートすればよいでしょう。

```
curl -XGET 'http://10.1.37.29:9200/ssp_nginx/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "fields": [ "status.200"],
  "sort": [
    {
      "_timestamp": { 
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
値は返ってくるのですが、こちらが想定している値と異なっているようです。図を追記いたしましたので、何かお気づきの点等ございましたらご一報頂けないでしょうか？
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: @Ezreal 画面中の"timestamp"はESの"_timestamp"とは別に、独自に定義したものですか？だとしたらアンダースコア_を削ってクエリーしてみてください。これでもうまくいかなければ、`curl http://10.1.37.29:9200/ssp_nginx/report/_mapping`の結果をおしらせください。なお、追記は質問の本文を編集するようにしてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！アンダースコアを削りましたところ、うまく想定通りの結果が返ってくれるようになりました。

Comment: お役に立てたようで良かったです:-)

Comment: （回答として投稿されていたコメントを質問にマージしようかと考えましたが、削除してしまっても概ね話が通りそうなのでそのようにしました）